# Javascript $.get not always updating on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm wondering why my code is not updating the the ajax call when I click on a button. It shows only after I do page refresh. My Code below:

Here is the complete jquery/javascript code:
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#savesubmainbutton").live('click',function(){

```
           $.post('save-sub-main.php',  $("#submainform").serialize(), function(data) {
              $('#submain_save_message').html(data);
            });

            $('#submain').hide();

            // Load data after submission
                $.get('getsubmain.php', { mainid: "<?php echo $_GET['id'];  ?>" },
                function(data) {
                  $('.submain_message').html(data);

                });



        });

    }); //end
```

This is the HTML form part

```
<div id="submain">

    <form id="submainform" name="submainform" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <table><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
    <!--<tr><td width="289" align="right">Jou naam:</td><td><input type="text" name="yourname" id="yourname" style="background-color:lightblue;" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="289" align="right">Jou e-posadres:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" style="background-color:lightblue;"/></td></tr>-->
    <tr><td width="289" align="right">Naam van die geskiedkundige figuur (bv. Jan van Riebeeck):</td><td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="289" align="right">Foto van die geskiedkundige figuur :</td><td><input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="289" align="right"><div id="filname"></div></td><td><input id="filename2" name="image" type="hidden" value=""  /></td></tr>
    <!--<tr><td width="289" align="right">Naam van jou inskrywing :</td><td><input type="text" name="title" id="title" /></td></tr>-->
    <tr><td width="289" align="right">Datum waarop die inskrywing gemaak is (bv. 1652):</td><td><input type="text" name="date" id="date" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="289" align="right">Status update (bv. Wat sien ek daar in die verte? Is dit 'n tafel?):</td><td><textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea></td></tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="mainid" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
    <tr><td></td><td><div id="savesubmainbutton" style="color:blue"><input type="button" value="Save" /></div></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Don't do this! `mainid: "<?php echo $_GET['id'];  ?>"`!! **NEVER** use request parameters without checking them first.

Comment: can you post your php/html code here (button)

Comment: can you post the markup also, it would help to put the various elements in your script in some sort of context.

Comment: mainid: "<?php echo $_GET['id'];  ?>" - Never put unescaped request parameters in your JavaScript like this. It's a security hole.

Comment: What @Tomalak is saying is **very important** because this is the classic example of how websites are XSS attacked.

Comment: Have you used Firebug to see what really happens with the Ajax requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember your ajax call is async - so the post has not returned the data before your get is executing - change your code as shown.

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

// Save SubMain data
    $("#savesubmainbutton").live('click',function(){

       $.post('save-sub-main.php',  $("#submainform").serialize(), function(data) {
          $('#submain_save_message').html(data);
          $('#submain').hide();

        // Load data after submission
            $.get('getsubmain.php', { mainid: "<?php echo $_GET['id'];  ?>" },
            function(data) {
              $('.submain_message').html(data);

            });

        });





    });
```

}); //end

Comment: THanks that little change help alot. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$.get` is not being called on the callback of your `$.post`. Thus the `$.get` is running but as the data hasn't been submitted yet it isn't returning any new data.

If you move the `$.get` to inside the callback it should work as expected.

Although it would be better and more efficient to not bother doing the second ajax call and instead just return the data from the `$.get` in the return data for the `$.post`.

Something like the below, assuming you are returning the data as a json object so you can simply have two variables for the two different parts of the response.

```
  $.post('save-sub-main.php',  $("#submainform").serialize(), function(data) {
       $('#submain_save_message').html(data.save_message);
       $('#submain').hide();
       $('.submain_message').html(data.return_data);
     },'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Get requests can be cached by the browser if they use the same parameters, see [here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajax-ie-caching-issue) for more details.

You can either use a POST or add a dummy parameter, something like ticks or current time, something that will differ to force the GET not to be cached.

Answer (score 0):

A few observations. If you want to replace the default submit behavior, it's best to ensure that the click event is cancelled else the default behavior of the form will take place.

Also, the post is asynchronous, so you need to ensure that any subsequent work you want performed is done in the callback function.